# Empty texture when baked

Tags: uv, texture-baking

I have main mesh and I also have another mesh that is painted and I need to transfer these colors to the main mesh for my work.

[image]

I did UV for my mesh. I also added a color attribute to the painted mesh. And for the main mesh, I connected the node of my UV.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I also present you my baking settings.

[image]

After all this baking, I get this result(Eyes are a different mesh):

[image]

I wanted to upload the blender file, but I couldn't reduce its size to 30 mb, so if you need it, here's a link to the Google drive:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qL7svun8eJ0Uxu5OfJ6BJ0JxCfbAvf5V/view?usp=sharing

UPD: My search has been going on for 7 days now, so I decided to add some more information.

My system:
CPU: Ryzen 5 5600H |
Video card: Gtx 1650 4 gb (studio drivers 536.99) |
16 gigabytes of RAM |
500 gb SSD M2

I used different drivers for the video card. I also watched a lot of baking videos to learn about possible errors. I looked at a lot of forums. I also fixed overlapping. I wanted to check if it was a computer problem. But I don't have any other computers or friends with computer to check.

Also, I noticed that if I don't clean up the image, I can see that the transparency is placed in the shape of my UV.(so I could assume that the problem is with taking the colors from the original model, but I'm not sure)

I decided to record a video of my actions. Because I can't find the answer and don't know why the baking doesn't work. Maybe I'm making some mistake and don't realize it. So if it helps, the video is available here:
https://youtu.be/GZMNrrCo6lk?si=Pt9XA0l9ByhzNUAh

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: It works fine for me, I baked onto the same object, created an Image Texture in the same material, but I had to unwrap the mesh because some faces were overlapping, the baking went right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I had made a very stupid mistake. I had accidentally turned on "disable on render" during the previous work on the model. And this little switch didn't let me bake properly...
[image]